# WebAPI how to disable another user from the admin

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I have created a simple WebAPI in Visual Studio C# to act as my backend to Angular.
Users can register via the Angular frontend and passed to a controller in the WebAPI to register that user in the backend DB (MSSql). All fine.

I am using token authentication from Angular to my API and using claims and roles to verify the user is logged in and has access to the requested controller.

How, as an Admin, can I disable another user so they are instantly locked out?

An example would be: A rogue user starts abusing the Angular application and I need to lock them down instantly and not to wait until their token expires and they are required to login again.

I could do a check in each and every controller to lookup the user in the DB and check their status and if I have set their status to "locked-out" then return say a 403 forbidden status from the controller but this seems a lot to lookup the user for each DB request they make.

Is there a "dot-net" way of doing it? I would love to be able, as the admin, to instantiate the said user, change their claim value for "status" to "locked-out" and I simply check their claim when making api requests but I can't see a way of changing another users claims.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't have to implement this in each and every controller. Check out "web.api authorization filter"

Comment: In addition to the filter suggested by @IvayloStoev you can create a .net delegating handler and hook it up early in your pipeline review all requests.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.MessageHandlers);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above, we have a handler in our pipeline that handles Authorization.  We do look at that Authorization header and parse it but all of the controllers rely on the already-parsed value that we hang in the Properties collection.  That way all AuthZ/AuthN occurs in this handler and whatever the handler sets in the Properties collection is what all of the application sees.

In your case the handler would need to be able to check whatever throttle or lockout you are using and replace the actual claims received with your "user is locked out" claims instead.